# Find then save and close all open Excel documents

Tags: excel, powershell, vbscript

I need help creating a PowerShell script that will find all open Excel documents, then first if the document is read only close the document without saving and suppress prompts if changes were made, or second if the document is not read only then save and close them. This script will be run from a scheduled task.

The reason why I want to do this is because I need an automated way of saving and closing documents on our shared production area computers. We have about 80 computers on our manufacturing shop floor area and these computers are setup like kiosks for our production workers to access programs and documents needed to do their work. These computers are locked down tight with group policy and only have access to specific applications. One of these applications has Excel documents linked within it for the production workers to open and edit (they don't ever create documents). But the problem is all too often these documents are left open far too long and many times they are also not saved. So my solution is to create a scheduled task (that runs in between our production shifts) to save and close all open Excel documents that are left open.

I have used this PowerShell script below to close other applications and it does work for Excel too if no changes were made... but obviously you'll get a prompt to save if there are changes so I need a way to save the Excel documents first before this runs (or if read only suppress the prompt and just close).

```
Get-Process EXCEL | Foreach-Object { $_.CloseMainWindow() | Out-Null }
```

If this can't be done with PowerShell I'm open to doing this with a VBScript instead.

Comment: You can do [this with vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20412010/vba-check-if-a-read-only-workbook-is-opened) with your own "master" workbook?

Comment: Are you saying create a "master" workbook with a vba script to save and close all other workbooks... then use PowerShell or vbscript in a scheduled task to launch that "master" workbook which will then save and close all other workbooks?

Comment: You can launch the master via something else but vba supports timers as well. Obviously, master box would then need to be up 24/7.

Comment: This would have to be something I can launch with a Windows scheduled task. I'll try this method using a "master" workbook. But ideally I'm hoping to get a response back saying this can be done with entirely with PowerShell.

Comment: It can, just post the vbscript below. ANY and ALL COM capable languages can connect to the file. You need to GetObject to the file (which you should know).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[@bgalea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35663542/1630171) had the right idea, but the answer is very incomplete. For one thing, re-attaching to COM objects only works in the context of the user who created the object, so you'd have to create either a scheduled task that runs as that particular user or a logoff script (automatically runs in a user's context at logoff).

Since you apparently want to run this periodically, a logoff script probably isn't an option, so you may want to use a logon script to create a respective scheduled task for each user, e.g. like this:

```cmd
schtasks /query /tn "Excel Cleanup" >nul 2>&1
if %errorlevel% neq 0 schtasks /create /tn "Excel Cleanup" /sc DAILY /tr "wscript.exe \"C:\path\to\your.vbs\"" /f
```

The VBScript run by these tasks might look somewhat like this:

```vb
On Error Resume Next
'attach to running Excel instance
Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
If Err Then
  If Err.Number = 429 Then
    'Excel not running (nothing to do)
    WScript.Quit 0
  Else
    'unexpected error: log and terminate
    CreateObject("WScript.Shell").LogEvent 1, Err.Description & _
      " (0x" & Hex(Err.Number) & ")"
    WScript.Quit 1
  End If
End If
On Error Goto 0

xl.DisplayAlerts = False  'prevent Save method from asking for confirmation
                          'about overwriting existing files (when saving new
                          'workbooks)
                          'WARNING: this might cause data loss!

For Each wb In xl.Workbooks
  wb.Save
  wb.Close False
Next

xl.Quit
Set xl = Nothing
```

If you want a PowerShell script instead of VBScript you need to use the [`GetActiveObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.getactiveobject.aspx) method to attach to a running Excel instance.

```bsh
try {
  # attach to running Excel instance
  $xl = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')
} catch {
  if ($_.Exception.HResult -eq -2146233087) {
    # Excel not running (nothing to do)
    exit 0
  } else {
    # unexpected error: log and terminate
    Write-EventLog -LogName Application `
      -Source 'Application Error' `
      -EventId 500 `
      -EntryType Error `
      -Message $_.Exception.Message
    exit 1
  }
}

$xl.DisplayAlerts = $false  # prevent Save() method from asking for confirmation
                            # about overwriting existing files (when saving new
                            # workbooks)
                            # WARNING: this might cause data loss!

foreach ($wb in $xl.Workbooks) {
  $wb.Save()
  $wb.Close($false)
}

$xl.Quit()
[void][Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::ReleaseComObject($xl)
[GC]::Collect()
[GC]::WaitForPendingFinalizers()
```

According to [Microsoft's documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176862.aspx) the [`GetObject()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.getobject(v=vs.110).aspx) method is supposed to work as well:

```
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.VisualBasic')
$xl = [Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction]::GetObject($null, 'Excel.Application')
```

but when I tried it I ended up with an additional (hidden) Excel instance instead of attaching to the already running one.

**Note:** If for some reason a user has started multiple Excel instances you will need to run the code once for each instance.

Comment: After testing getobject, using only the filename without the classname connects.

Comment: @bgalea I'm using `GetObject` to attach directly to the application object, not a particular workbook, so that the code doesn't need to know a filename.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers answer is exactly what I was looking for. This script by Ansgar doesn't need to know the filename, which is what I needed since there are over 1000 different Excel files in 100's of different directories that could be opened. Thank you very much!

Comment: Except that connecting to an app object creates a new process. I repeat my comments. Your code doesn't work. See my edit. @ Ansgar Wiechers

Comment: @bgalea The code I posted is tested and works. I'm not making this up.

Comment: Well not on Excel 20003 (aka Office XP). On both Vista and Windows 10. My guess is Excel takes a reference to itself on the app object.

Comment: Also people keep posting questions about Excel.Application not exiting when the reference is closed. There is some issue here.

Comment: @bgalea The code is tested with Office 97 and Office 2010. I seriously doubt that it doesn't work with Office 2003 unless you made a mistake somewhere. Also, the code samples contain everything required to dispose of the lingering process.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I don't know if you will read this, but I tried your code and it works fine. The only thing I noticed is, that all add-ons I use will close aswell. If I open Excel again, they will not show. I have to restart my PC to be able to access the add-ons again. Is there a way arround this?

Comment: @MarcoGetrost That is a different question, and probably one that belongs on [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 0):

```
Set xlBook = GetObject("C:\Users\David Candy\Documents\Super.xls", "Excel.Application")
For each wsheet in xlbook.worksheets
    msgbox wsheet.name
next
```

VBScript, JScript, PS, VBA can all do it. Above is VBScript (and thus also VBA). The technology is COM not a language.

**EDIT**

As said using the app object doesn't work in excel.

A excel file opened.

```
EXCEL.EXE                    13560 Console                    1     19,228 K Running         DESKTOP-UCDGI39\David Candy
                             0:00:00 Microsoft Excel - Super.xls
```

Running GetObject using Excel.Application

```
EXCEL.EXE                    13560 Console                    1     19,236 K Running         DESKTOP-UCDGI39\David Candy
                             0:00:00 Microsoft Excel - Super.xls
EXCEL.EXE                    15124 Console                    1     12,772 K Running         DESKTOP-UCDGI39\David Candy
                             0:00:00 N/A
```

**NOTE**

- Separate process
- Not started with COM switches (/a or /automation and
  /embedding)
- No access to the other excel

This is in addition to other faulty behaviour by excel where it won't exit memory when references are released.