# What is the best practice to capture an open Excel document as a COM Object (not creating a new one) on Windows using PowerShell

Tags: excel, windows, powershell, automation, rpa

I try to automate my workflow on my day-to-day job. Since Excel is frequently used. Using PowerShell for Excel automation is crucial for me.

Most of the time I do have my Excel windows open. Thus I use below code block to capture these windows for further automation:

```cs
$FullPath = $FilePath  + "\" + $WorkBookName 

$excel = [Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject("Excel.Application")
#capture already active object
if (($excel.Workbooks | ? {$_.Fullname}).FullName -eq $FullPath) {
    $wb = $excel.workbooks | ?{$_.FullName -eq $FullPath}
} else {
    # if no document is available open from filepath
    $excel, $wb = Open-NewCliExcel -TypeOrPath $FullPath
}
```

I'm pretty sure that there must be more stable and reliable practices in terms of scalability. My plan is to build an intra-company library to start the automation of other people's processes.

Comment: What you have there is the way it's done.

Comment: Thank you for edit.. Would you suggest any exception handling statements to use for this codeblock?

Comment: [Of course](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35671136/1630171).

Comment: Very useful, appreciated!